# Temporary support wall

Tags: framing

I need to build a temporary support wall in order to replace a sole plate in an exterior load bearing wall that has termite damage. I will access from inside the house. There is a crawl space/basement beneath this spot.

Question: how close to this wall should the temporary support be? I’ll need some room to work. Can I place the top plate of the support wall directly against the ceiling drywall or do I need to remove part of the ceiling to expose the studs? Should I use two by sixes for the support wall? Do I need to build a second support wall in the basement directly beneath?

A certified structural engineer will provide and inspection and plans.

[image]

Comment: Would remove the drywall.  Drywall is quite spongy with weight/force.  Will probably dent at least.  Basement depends on which direction the joists are, if parallel with the wall, then yes.

Comment: If the floor joists are attached to the sill plate in any way then, yes, you would probably want to support the joists from the basement. Also, bear in mind that any load on the main floor temp wall will transfer to the floor joists - you probably want to go ahead and pass that load straight down to the basement floor instead of having it sit on the floor joists several inches (or more) from their ends.

Comment: if there is termite damage in the baseboard, isn't it likely there is some in the vertical studs?

Comment: the ceiling joists running parallel to this wall, how do I build a temporary support wall when the joists are like that?